# Windows 10 iot core 802.1X authentication for wired connection Raspberry

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10-iot-core

i am wondering if its possible to achieve 802.1X (LPEAP) authentication for wired network on Windows iot core running on a Raspberry Pi.
Searching the web for a couple of days didnt result in any answers.
Its ok if i have to implement the authentication in a separate app or driver add-on that i have to write.

Do anyone have some information about it.

Comment: At the moment, 802.1X (LPEAP) authentication is not supported on Windows IoT Core.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for your reply. May there any way to implement it manually? I got the point that this requires a OSI layer 2 communication. I tried to figure out if there are any possibilities to get winpcap driver running on windows 10 iot core. But did not found any right hint for that. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Sorry, there is no more details about that.